# Using DateOffset alongside date type in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

|  | start_date | var 1 | ... | total_months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/10/2022 | 1.0 |  | 14 |
| 2 | 24/08/2023 | 0.0 |  | 2 |

'start_date' is a date type: '<M8[ns]' and 'total_months' is an integer which basically details the number of months since the starts date. The data also includes lots of variables like var 1 for example.

I've been trying to use start_date and total_months to create a 'final_date'/'end_date' variable but I'm having no luck.

The code I currently have is:

> from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
>
> df['final_date'] = df['start_date'].apply(lambda x: DateOffset(month =
> df.loc[x,'total_months'].astype(int)))

But I keep getting 'Keyerror: Timestamp' followed by a date from the dataset. Does anyone know whats causing this?
I've used the DateOffset before but just with a constant number x and its worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `pd.to_timedelta` no longer supports 'M' and 'Y' units, you need to process the date yourself:

```
# Convert as DatetimeIndex if needed
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Compute year and month offsets
y = df['start_date'].dt.year + (df['total_months'] // 12)
m = df['start_date'].dt.month + (df['total_months'] % 12)
d = df['start_date'].dt.day

# Set the end date
end_date = pd.concat([y, m, d], keys=['year', 'month', 'day'], axis=1)
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(end_date)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  start_date  var 1  total_months   end_date
1 2022-10-10    1.0            14 2023-12-10
2 2023-08-24    0.0             2 2023-10-24
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, this does. I also found another way which I will add as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find another way to get to my answer by using a function:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

def Offset(r):
    return DateOffset(months = r)

df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + df['total_months'].apply(Offset)
```

This gave:

| start_date | var_1 | ... | total_months | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/10/2022 | 1.0 |  | 14 | 10/12/2023 |
| 24/08/2023 | 0.0 |  | 2 | 24/10/2023 |

Comment: Yes you can do it but it can be very slow because `apply` happens on each record.